# max_input_vars Issue and 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: php, apache, http-post

I am facing a weird issue. I have searched a lot but can't find anything about this problem.

When a **POST** request is made to a certain URL with **more than 1000 vars**, it gives a **301 response**.

I changed the **max_input_vars in php.ini to allow 20000 variables**.

Now **phpinfo() shows the updated value of max_input_vars**.

But still the response to the POST request is **301 Moved Permanently** if the variable count exceeds 1000.

Any thoughts?

Comment: try increasing post_max_size too.

Comment: its 800mb and the POST data is 32kb

Comment: not sure but may be increasing max_input_time will help.